# Progress bar in uploading files using URL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file, url

I am uploading files through URL in PHP, ajax. I need a progress bar that shows how much file has been uploaded.

Please see what I am using in my code.

PHP code

```
$upload_url = $_REQUEST['upload_url'];

$arr_upload_file = explode("/",$upload_url);
$ext = $arr_upload_file[count($arr_upload_file)-1];
$file = md5(mt_rand(0,1000) . implode(getdate()) . $ext) . '-' . $ext;
//echo $_SERVER[']
$app->sessions->get_var('folder_id');
$path = 'C:/wamp/www/bigoshare/uploads/';

$uploadss = file_put_contents($path.$file,file_get_contents($upload_url));
$size = getimagesize($path.$file);
$totsize = strlen(file_get_contents($upload_url));
```

Ajax code

```
$('#url_upload_btn').live('click', function () {

    $('#progress_container').fadeIn(100); //fade in progress bar
    $('#progress_bar').width("50%"); //set width of progress bar based on the $status value (set at the top of this page)
    $('#progress_completed').html("50%");
    upload_url = $('#txt_url_link').val();
    setInterval("getinterdata()", 1000);
    var dataString = 'upload_url=' + upload_url;
    $.ajax({
        url: App.url + '/allusers/uploadbyurl/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: dataString,
        success: function (data) {

            $('#uploads').prepend($.trim(data));

            $('.show_url_Upload_div').hide();
        }
    });


});

function getinterdata() {

    $.ajax({
        url: App.url + '/allusers/getuploadpercentage/',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

    });

}
```

When I am executing the above code seconde ajax only responds after the complete upload of file while i need at the time of uploading and in progress.

Comment: You are not given html code. i think your **progress_container** id is missing

Comment: main problem is that second ajax is not responding untill first ajax does not completes.

Answer (score 0):

Dont reinvent the wheel ;) There are dozens of tested and debugged plugins for jquery file uploads with progress bars. Just pick one.

I personally like [1] this one a lot. Simple to use, good documentation and powerful enough.

you might want to look at [2]: the block at "how-to-display-upload-progress-with-the-basic-plugin" should be pretty helpful!

[1] http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

[2] https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

Comment: I am able to do manage progress bar for files which are stored on our server.Question is > I am uploading files from url.

Comment: shouldnt it be easy to change the source of the value that is submitted to be uploaded? When you select a file from local file system it should use some kind of "url" ... but still: you could go and have a look how the plugin handles the issue of handling both actions at the same time.